# Angular4 - pass form data straight to pipe

Tags: angular, typescript

In my html i have a few form fields which i want to pass to a custom pipe for filtering:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter1"></td>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter2"></td>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter3"></td>

<tr *ngFor="let a of arr | myFilter: filter1:filter2:filter3;>
  ...
</tr>
```

But for this to work i have to define all the filters in my class:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  filter1;
  filter2;
  filter3;
}
```

and this doesent seem very clean. Is there a better solution where i dont have to define these filters in my class?

Comment: I can't understand what's the problem. Can you elaborate your question?

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach to using pipes would be to maintain a model class that contains the array that your *ngFor would bind to. You could have setters on model properties that filter that array when the user input changes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks clean and simple.

```
export class MyFilter implements PipeTransform {    
  transform(value:any, arg1:any, arg2:any,arg3:any):any {
        ...
}
```

As you need three values to transform the data your using this way.

Comment: Since the 1st. parameter is the `array`, your declaration is missing a parameter. It should be `transform(value: any, arg1: any, arg2: any, arg3: any): any {`